# how to determine if there are numbers can be add up to 10 in a 4x4 grid?

Tags: algorithm, grid

At the beginning, generating a 4x4 grid like the first grid

Notice that all numbers are less than 6.

[image: Grid]

Player can add more than 2 numbers together to get number 10 (those numbers must be neighbours of each other)
if the number is greater than 10, it only can be add up with itself, like 10+10=20, 20+20=40...160+160=320

How can I determine that the adding all the numbers does not sum up to 10, shown as the 2nd grid (even the 6+4=10 but they are not neighbor)?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. If you could make your question less complicated and explain more upon what you are struggling with surely there would be more help.